# Django models.OneToOneField(User) not able to access data by user.profile in profile.html

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display the fields qualification and name that I defined in my Profiles>>models.py file to show on the web page itself. I am trying to call the info with user.profile.name and user.profile.qualification.all but it doesnt find it

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserQualifications(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    normalizedName = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Profiles(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")

    qualification = models.ManyToManyField(UserQualifications, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    isHighSchoolGraduate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isUndergraduate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isCollegeGraduate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isDoctor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isExpert = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profiles'
```

profile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{%  block content %}
    <h1>
        {{ user.get_full_name }} (@{{ user.username }})
    </h1>

    {%  with profile=user.profile %}
        {% if profiles %}

            <h2>
                {{ profile.name|default:"" }}
            </h2>

            <br/>
            <div>
                Qualifications:
                {% for qualifacation in profile.qualification.all %}

                    <span>
                        {{ qualifacation.name }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
                    </span>

                {% endfor %}
            </div>

        {% endif %}

    {% endwith %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Does the user have a `Profiles` [sic]? It will not be created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use related name profile instead of profiles

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{%  block content %}
    <h1>
        {{ user.get_full_name }} (@{{ user.username }})
    </h1>

    {%  with profile=user.profile %}
        {% if profile %}    # not sure but trying using profile instead of profiles here as you are using related name profile

            <h2>
                {{ profile.name|default:"" }}
            </h2>

            <br/>
            <div>
                Qualifications:
                {% for qualifacation in profile.qualification.all %}

                    <span>
                        {{ qualifacation.name }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
                    </span>

                {% endfor %}
            </div>

        {% endif %}
```